# Help with proving a set contains the $0$ vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following set

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(x) \\
\sin(x)\\
0
\end{bmatrix} \Biggm | x \in \mathbb R \right\}
$$
and I need to show that this is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. I understand that I need to show that the set contains the $0$ vector, that the set is closed under addition and multiplication, but what I am unsure of is how to go about showing that the set contains the $0$ vector.

What I am thinking is that $x$ has to be the same for $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$, which would mean that the set does not contain the $0$ vector because there is no $x$ that can be inserted into the set which would give $0$.

Or is it the case that I just need to find something to multiply the set by to produce the $0$ vector?

For addition is it possible to do something like

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(x) \\
\sin(x)\\
0
\end{bmatrix} 
+ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(x) \\
\sin(x)\\
0
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
2\cos(x) \\
2\sin(x)\\
0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

which would prove that the set is not closed under addition because $2\cos(x) \neq \cos(2x)$

Comment: well.. this is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$... As you said it is not closed under addition (sin and cos can only take values in [-1,1]) and does not contain zero.

Comment: what is the multiplication of this vector space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are never simultaneously equal to 0, indeed:
$$\sin^2x + \cos^2x=1$$

Comment: Indeed! That was I suppose the basis for my thinking that the set doesn't contain the 0 vector. I suppose I was simply confused as to whether I had to determine that by setting something in for x or by multiplying the vector by something.

Comment: It suffice that you show that for every v we have |v|=1 thus $v\neq0$.

Comment: You can also find $v$ and $w$ in the set such that v+w=0 notably by choosing $x=\pm{\pi}{4}$ but it doesn't mean that it is a subspace.

Comment: Answer is so good. Let $u=0$ for suitable $x$. Take $v\in \Bbb R^3$ with same entries $u$. Then $uv=cos^{2}(x)+sin^{2}(x)=0$. This is a contradiction.